# Code stops running after input. Console gives message: "(exit value: -1)"

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code that does a poisson-proces, and the code has to three inputs lambda, the start date and the end date.

```
    cout << "\nLambda: ";
    cin >> lambda;
    cout << "Start date 'dd.mm.yyyy': ";
    cin >> t0date;
    cout << "End date 'dd.mm.yyyy': ";
    cin >> tsdate;
```

The code then goes on, but the program stops running at the last input `cin >> tsdate`

I'm still pretty new to programming, but I still fell like this code should work, and not stop at: ```cin >> tsdate``

This is the code I've written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

const int nmax = 50;

int dayinmonth(string Dato);
void random_number(double &p);

int main() {
    double p=0,dt[nmax],t[nmax],lambda;
    int t0,ts,k=1, N;
    string t0date,tsdate;

    cout << "\nLambda: ";
    cin >> lambda;
    cout << "Start date 'dd.mm.yyyy': ";
    cin >> t0date;
    cout << "End date 'dd.mm.yyyy': ";
    cin >> tsdate;

    t0 = dayinmonth(t0date);
    ts = dayinmonth(tsdate);


    t[0] = t0;
    do{
        random_number(p);
        dt[k] = (-1/lambda) * log(1-p);
        t[k] = t[k-1] + dt[k];
        k = k +1;
    }while(t[k] < ts);
    N = k -1;
    cout << endl << "N: " << N << endl;

    cout << "\nt_k: "
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cout << endl << t[k];
    }
}
int dayinyear(string Dato){
    string il;
    int mth, daymth,day;
    int Days[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    mth = 0; daymth = 0; il = Dato;

    mth =  ((il[3] - '0') * 10 + (il[4] - '0')) -1;
    daymth = (il[0] - '0') * 10 +(il[1] - '0');

    day = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<mth; i++) day += Days[i];
    day += daymth;

    return day;
}
void random_number(double &p) {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution <double> dis(0.0, 1.0);
    p = dis(gen);
}
```

I'm using eclipse and the console say the following when i stops:
" (exit value: -1)".

Normally it says " (exit value: 0)". Maybe thats helpful for solving the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: in this code **dayinmonth** function declared but definition could not found.

Comment: What happens if the do/while loop takes more that 49 iterations?

Comment: Comment out all the code from `t0 = dayinmonth(t0date);` to the end of `main()`. Does the problem still occur? If so, there's something wrong with the input that you're giving the program. If not, uncomment `t0 = dayinmonth(t0date);`. Does the problem occur now? If so, `dayinmonth` is the culprit. If not, add something more back in. Repeat until done.

Comment: It's not ```dayinmonth(t0date);``` that's the problem, I've tried removing it from the program, still stops.

Comment: Anyone who knows what ```<terminated> (exit value: -1)``` in the console means?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly named function **dayinmonth** in given code.
Or i can say you have not defined function **dayinmonth**.
Or change name of function  **dayinyear**  to  **dayinmonth** .

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally got the code to work. I changed the do-while loop to a for-loop and then it worked, I have no idea why do-loop didn't work.
If anyone knows why, please tell.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

const int nmax = 50;

int dayinyear(string Dato);
void random_number(double &p);

int main() {
    double p=0,dt[nmax],t[nmax],lambda;
    int t0,ts,k, N;
    string t0date,tsdate;

    cout << "\nLambda: ";
    cin >> lambda;
    cout << "Start date 'dd.mm.yyyy': ";
    cin >> t0date;
    cout << "End date 'dd.mm.yyyy': ";
    cin >> tsdate;

    t0 = dayinyear(t0date);
    ts = dayinyear(tsdate);

    t[0] = 0  ;
    for( k=1; k<1000; k++){
        random_number(p);
        dt[k] = (-1/lambda) * log(1-p);
        t[k] = t[k-1] + dt[k];
        if(t[k]>ts) break;
    }
    N = k -1;
    cout << endl << "N: " << N << endl;

    cout << "\nt_k: ";
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++){
        cout << endl << t[i];
    }
}
int dayinyear(string Dato){
    string il;
    int mth, daymth,day;
    int Days[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    mth = 0; daymth = 0; il = Dato;

    mth =  ((il[3] - '0') * 10 + (il[4] - '0')) -1;
    daymth = (il[0] - '0') * 10 +(il[1] - '0');

    day = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<mth; i++) day += Days[i];
    day += daymth;

    return day;
}
void random_number(double &p) {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution <double> dis(0.0, 1.0);
    p = dis(gen);
}
```

It's pretty much the same, but works without any problem.